# New Minitest plugin is not working

Tags: minitest

```
# sample_test.rb
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'

module Minitest
    def self.plugin_bogus_options(opts, options)
    end 

    def self.plugin_bogus_init(options)
      p "Writing first pluging"
    end 
end

class SomeTest < Minitest::Test
   def test_that_it_passes
     assert_equal true, true
   end 
end
```

When I execute `ruby sample_test.rb` it doesn't print anything. Where I went wrong. Could you help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your bogus plugin needs to be in a file at the following path:

```
minitest/bogus_plugin.rb:
```

Minitest will scan for files that match the `minitest/*_plugin.rb` patterns and activate them.

Comment: I did same as you suggested. Here is the code `https://github.com/sivagollapalli/bogus-plugin` but still problem persists. Could you check?

Answer (score 0):

If you still struggling with that and for anyone with this problem, I found the answer here : http://www.samuelmullen.com/2013/11/extending-minitest-5-progress-reporters/

"In the `::load_plugins` method in the **minitest.rb** file of Minitest, it uses `Gem::find_files` to search for plugins. The `::find_files` method uses the `$LOAD_PATH` global variable to determine which directories in which to look. So, in order for Minitest to find your plugins, you’ll either need to create it as a Gem, or push your directory onto the `$LOAD_PATH` array."